# Xcode is telling me "cannot find 'com' in scope for the set IOS bundle ID method for firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

Below is the code & the method setIOSBundleID returns an error saying it cannot find 'com' in scope... not sure why any leads?

```
func emailCodeAuth(){
        let actionCodeSettings = ActionCodeSettings()
        actionCodeSettings.setIOSBundleID(com.IMHOTECHP.GiveMe!)
        actionCodeSettings.handleCodeInApp = true
        actionCodeSettings.url = URL(string: "giveme-d7861.firebaseapp.com")
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `setIOSBundleID` (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/ActionCodeSettings.Builder#public-actioncodesettings.builder-setiosbundleid-string-iosbundleid) takes a `String` as a parameter. That means that you probably want to be wrapping your parameter in quotes:

```
actionCodeSettings.setIOSBundleID("com.IMHOTECHP.GiveMe")
```